# Changing CSV data source based on input range

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a visualization that changes the data source based on user input via an input element. The input element is a range type and has min and max values corresponding to the years 1946-2020. I have CSV files for each year and want to change the data source based on the value of the input range. I already have an event listener for the input element to update text appended to the SVG, but what I don't know how to do is change the CSV file as well.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  },
  width = 1260 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 630 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale
  .linear()
  .domain([0, 20])
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale
  .linear()
  .domain([0, 15])
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20,610)")
  .call(xAxis.ticks(20).tickSize(0).tickPadding(10))
  .append("text")
  .attr("id", "year")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", -height / 2)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("1946");

d3.csv("championships/1946.csv", function(error, data) {
  svg.selectAll(".logo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.logo;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.championships);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.stack);
    })
    .attr("width", "40")
    .attr("height", "40");
});

d3.select("#slider").on("input", function() {
  update(+this.value);
});

function update(slider) {
  d3.select("#year").text(slider);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="1946" max="2020" step="1" value="1946">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to call the `d3.csv` function from within the `update()` function, and use the `slider` value to construct the file path. On StackOverflow this doesn't work, because I don't have your files, but you can see that the calls are made. They just fail.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  },
  width = 1260 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 630 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale
  .linear()
  .domain([0, 20])
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale
  .linear()
  .domain([0, 15])
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20,610)")
  .call(xAxis.ticks(20).tickSize(0).tickPadding(10))
  .append("text")
  .attr("id", "year")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", -height / 2)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("1946");

d3.select("#slider").on("input", function() {
  update(+this.value);
});

function update(slider) {
  d3.select("#year").text(slider);

  d3.csv("championships/" + slider + ".csv", function(error, data) {
    console.log("Read data for", slider);
    if (error !== undefined) return;
    svg.selectAll(".logo")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d.logo;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.championships);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.stack);
      })
      .attr("width", "40")
      .attr("height", "40");
  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="1946" max="2020" step="1" value="1946">
</div>
```